# "touch file" in dired mode

Tags: init-file, dired, files, customize, find-file

I found this answer:

```
(eval-after-load 'dired
  '(progn
     (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "c") 'my-dired-create-file)
     (defun create-new-file (file-list)
       (defun exsitp-untitled-x (file-list cnt)
         (while (and (car file-list) (not (string= (car file-list) (concat "untitled" (number-to-string cnt) ".txt"))))
           (setq file-list (cdr file-list)))
         (car file-list))

       (defun exsitp-untitled (file-list)
         (while (and (car file-list) (not (string= (car file-list) "untitled.txt")))
           (setq file-list (cdr file-list)))
         (car file-list))

       (if (not (exsitp-untitled file-list))
           "untitled.txt"
         (let ((cnt 2))
           (while (exsitp-untitled-x file-list cnt)
             (setq cnt (1+ cnt)))
           (concat "untitled" (number-to-string cnt) ".txt")
           )
         )
       )
     (defun my-dired-create-file (file)
       (interactive
        (list (read-file-name "Create file: " (concat (dired-current-directory) (create-new-file (directory-files (dired-current-directory))))))
        )
       (write-region "" nil (expand-file-name file) t) 
       (dired-add-file file)
       (revert-buffer)
       (dired-goto-file (expand-file-name file))
       )
     )
  )
```

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300137/how-to-create-new-file-from-dired-mode). It does what I like, which is that pressing `c` will create a new file in `dired` mode, but what I don't like is that it's by default named `untitled.txt`. For example, if I press `c` in `dired` with this inside `~/.emacs.d` I get `Create file: ~/.emacs.d/untitled.text`, but what I want is `Create file: ~/.emacs.d/` so I can pick the name myself. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `C-h f read-file-name`, read the doc string and decide what behavior you want: in particular, you'll need to think about what to do if the user just presses RET at that point without entering a name.

Comment: Isn't that an issue even here if they get rid of `untitled.txt` @NickD ?